# How to ask for a sequence of detailed steps guidance clearly and politely?

Tags: politeness, sentence-request

I asked a [question](https://superuser.com/q/1488304/1093117) just now.

> Please give a specific setting path, from which menu command to submenu command.

I am worried about if I say it clearly and politely.

I meant to express that something like a sequence of detailed steps, something like the following

1. Clicking the menu command A1
2. Clicking the menu command A1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can you please tell me the exact sequence of steps that I need to follow, including what item to select from each pull-down menu and each submenu?

To be polite when asking for information, any of these are good:

> Can you please tell me _____?
>
> Could you please tell me _____?
>
> Will you please tell me _____?
>
> Would you please tell me _____?

"Could" is softer than "can", and "would" is softer than "will". "Can" is the least formal, but it's a level of formality appropriate to StackExchange.

The word "path" usually suggests something spatial in English, like a curving dirt trail through a forest. You can make "path" mean something more abstract, like a sequence of commands, but this is a little unusual. For actions that you do when operating a computer program, "steps" is a good noun and "follow" is a good verb for "steps". "The exact sequence of steps" emphasizes that you want to know every detail.

Comment: Thanks a lot. No offense, did you ever ask for this kind of guidance by using that long sentence?

Comment: @fuDL I have never used exactly that sentence. However, I used to write user's manuals professionally. The words _item, select, pull-down menu,_ and _submenu_ are very clear and specific. That clarity and specificity costs a few extra words. The words from _Can_ to _follow_ are also a little longer than usual, but they emphasize the high level of detail that you want. For a native speaker, the sentence really does not seem very long. I hope you get a good answer!